# how to get dropwizard metrics web ui

Tags: dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I am trying to give some web user interface to the dropwizard metrics. Checked Graphite and Ganglia but I need something which can be easily installed on windows and linux,as well.
Could not configure metrics-watcher because the metrics in my application are dynamic. Also configured jclawson/metrics-ui but did not find the ui appealing. Please suggest me if there are any other sources which can be easily integrated.

Comment: Possibly not useful but https://github.com/dbaggott/newrelic-dropwizard with newrelic will give basic response times via a web user interface

Comment: Thanks Matt Freake.
Decided to go with GraphiteReporter. Actually my metrics contain sql queries and urls. SQL queries, as they contain commas and dots, Graphite is unable to display the metrics, same with urls, problem is with { and } characters. Please help me if there is some fix or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipelined the metrics to Kibana. I was expecting a web interface where can I search the metrics contents, configuring meaningful widgets and dashboards for the same, Kibana fulfills my requirement.